# How to add Image in bootstrap-vue rounded corner

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to use bootstrap-vue to create an application. My Application contains a navigation bar, on top right of it. I am trying to add an circular image. I some how found out on how to add a block color circular shape. But I am not able to add Image on it

I tried using different attributes and props to make it work. But it is not working. I am using `<b-img>` tag to make images responsive. This is the piece of code i referred to from https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/image/

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-img v-bind="mainProps" rounded alt="Rounded image"></b-img>
    <b-img v-bind="mainProps" rounded="top" alt="Top-rounded image"></b-img>
    <b-img v-bind="mainProps" rounded="right" alt="Right-rounded image"></b-img>
    <b-img v-bind="mainProps" rounded="bottom" alt="Bottom-rounded image"></b-img>
    <b-img v-bind="mainProps" rounded="left" alt="Left-rounded image"></b-img>
    <b-img v-bind="mainProps" rounded="circle" alt="Circle image"></b-img>
    <b-img v-bind="mainProps" rounded="0" alt="Not rounded image"></b-img>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        mainProps: { blank: true, blankColor: '#777', width: 75, height: 75, class: 'm1' }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here is my code:

NavigationBar.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="light">
      <b-navbar-brand href="#">
        <img src="./../assets/logo.png" alt="logo" />
      </b-navbar-brand>
      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">        
          <b-button size="sm" variant="light">
            <b-img v-bind="imageSetter" rounded="circle" alt="Profile"></b-img>
            <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1"  class="m-2" dropleft variant="light">
              <b-dropdown-item>Profile</b-dropdown-item>
              <b-dropdown-item>CPPI</b-dropdown-item>
              <b-dropdown-item>Cred</b-dropdown-item>              
              <b-dropdown-item>Settings</b-dropdown-item>              
              <b-dropdown-item>Logout</b-dropdown-item>              
            </b-dropdown>
          </b-button>

      </b-navbar-nav>  
    </b-navbar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'NavigationBar',
  data() {
    return {
      imageSetter: {
        blank: false, width: 50, height: 50, class: 'm1'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

</style>
```

I know, there must be an attribute i can pass to. But, I am not able to find it.

How do i add the rounded image on it?

Thanks

EDIT:
When i passed the src attribute inline. and checked while doing inspect it shows the correct path to the image but its not displaying.

[image]

Comment: The only thing missing is the `src` attribute on you `<b-img>`, other than that everything looks fine.

Comment: I tried adding it. But it did'nt work.
I tried passing src as a data (under script) as well as passing it inline.
None of them worked

Comment: I've tried the same code and it works. Does the image load correctly ?

Comment: No! I think there is some issue with path. I tried playing with it. Even though it did'nt. can you show the code that you tried?

Comment: My code is the same with an image saved in the assets directory. Unfortunately its difficult to understand the path issue in your code, without looking at the project structure. If you fix the path the rounded corner classes would apply only then.

Comment: Did you set the path relative from the index.html or relative from the component where the code exist?

My Project structure is same... components are stored under `src/components/`
assets are stored under `src/assets/`

Comment: Its relative to the component `src="../assets/image.png"`

Comment: I did'nt work for me :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194601/discussion-between-abhigyan-nayak-and-stephen-s).